# Redirect to a different url for 1st time visit to any pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I redirect the user to a different url if it is the 1st time the user visits any page of the site?

If it only requires this for the home page, I can add the code like below in the home controller:

```
string cookieName = "NotFirstTimeVisit";
if (!HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(cookieName))
{
    // first time, add a cookie.
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    cookie.Value = "True";
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirstTimeVisitUrl"];
    // redirect to the page for first time visit.
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

But the issue is: the user may not browse homepage at the 1st visit. For example, the user may get a share link, i.e. https://example.com/shared_001/002 , then it will not be redirected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered putting the cookie logic in an ActionFilter that way you can just apply the filter to do the check which would run regardless of url.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a demo for redirect user to URL only for the 1st time from whole application.
You have to **override OnActionExecuting** method for check whether the user was redirected or not early.

**1. Create one class for Override Action Filter (Before Action Filter).**

```
namespace Example.Helper
{
    public class ValidateUserLoggedIn : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Method for redirect to url first time only
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                string cookieName = "NotFirstTimeVisit";
                if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(cookieName))
                {
                    // first time, add a cookie.
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
                    cookie.Value = "True";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                    // You can add your URL here
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                                                    new RouteValueDictionary
                                                                    (new
                                                                    {
                                                                        controller = "Department",
                                                                        action = "Index"
                                                                    }
                                                                ));
                }
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Call above method to the controller, global file, per action according to your requirement.**

```
namespace Example.Controllers
{
    [ValidateUserLoggedIn] // Action Filter class
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }
   }
}
```

**Note: Let me know if you have any query on the above code. Thanks!**